# While taking pull from VS code.This conflict message pops up

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

```
$ git pull --tags origin development
* branch            development -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting.
```

**I just need to know know how can i compare the changes that other user made along with mine and to accept both changes or revert accordingly.**

Comment: `git diff HEAD origin/development` will show the changes between the two branches

Comment: How can i accept the change

Comment: Don’t use `git pull` if you just want to compare branches with `git diff` or something. `git pull` (with default configuration) attempts a merge. Use `git fetch` instead of you don’t want a merge (again, at least with the default behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from git is pretty self-explanatory... one of the files you have modified in your working tree would be affected by that `git pull` so git is warning you about it and avoiding the merge because of it. The easiest way to deal with it is:

```
git stash save "coming back"
git pull --more-options-as-needed
git stash pop
```

Or, in your case, add `--autostash` in `git pull`. Notice the warning from `git help pull`:

```
       --autostash, --no-autostash
           Automatically create a temporary stash entry before the operation begins, record it in the special
           ref MERGE_AUTOSTASH and apply it after the operation ends. This means that you can run the
           operation on a dirty worktree. However, use with care: the final stash application after a
           successful merge might result in non-trivial conflicts.
```